# kerberos authentication setup for postgresql in REDHAT environment

Tags: linux, postgresql, rhel, database-administration, system-administration

Our backend is running with PostgreSql in REDHAT environment.Here we need to implement a kerberos authentication.what will be the configuration changes required to perform this.

example: google. once we login to google.com we can access google+, google drive, google apps.. without again providing password.

Comment: PostgreSQL Version ??

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-methods.html#KERBEROS-AUTH **and** http://jpmens.net/2012/06/23/postgresql-and-kerberos/

Answer (score 0):

I too need a similar setup. but my requirment is my client wants to connect through windows as front-end where RHEL is using as backend. so, i have a vague idea thats going to work out with Active Directory configuration. but guide me on how to setup kerberos using AD on RHEL.